# Auditing entities when using custom SQL command (batch delete)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

I use NHibernate and Envers to access my bdd and audit my entites. The problem is entites are not audited when I use a custom SQL command (to delete a lots of entries).

Is there a way to manually trigger audit for a bunch of entries?

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 1):

No. Entities that nhibernate aren't aware of, envers won't be either.

You should handle this manually.